# Can I make a simple browser plugin for both desktop and mobile?

Tags: android, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, desktop

I wanted to use Chrome but it looks like Chrome for Android can't run extensions? And support in Firefox seems shaky.

All I want is to request and execute remote CSS and JS files for a particular domain. I don't need any UI or anything.

Not sure if I should just forge ahead with Firefox or perhaps think about rolling my own 'browser' with plugin embedded?

Comment: Yep its easy to make a 2 in 1 for firefox. This is an example of one: https://github.com/diegocr/GitHubExtIns/ here are the addon-sdk mobile docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Mobile_development#Module_Compatibility especially with no UI its the exact same page-worker module i think

Comment: Here's another nice resource on how to make it across platforms: https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2014/06/05/how-to-develop-firefox-extension/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Firefox SDK, available here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK

It allows you to develop for both platforms. And if you have troubles with sdk in firefox for android, you can read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_for_Android

If no UI is required, it will be easy to set up :)

Regarding comments in this post, I made a script for setting up the under development extension:

```
# Run this script from your project base dir.
#1 - Complete the following vars:
#ANDROID_APP_ID=org.mozilla.fennec;
ANDROID_APP_ID=org.mozilla.firefox_beta; 
#ANDROID_APP_ID=org.mozilla.firefox;
APP_NAME="YourExtensionName";
OUTPUT_DIR=$HOME/Bureau;
FILES="./";
EXCLUDE="-xr!./.git";
CLEAN_APP_DATA=false;

#2 - This will clear all your app cache
if [ "$CLEAN_APP_DATA" == "true" ]; then
    adb shell pm clear $ANDROID_APP_ID
fi

#3 - This will create the XPI file
7z a -r $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.xpi $FILES $EXCLUDE;

#4 - This will copy the XPI to the phone SD card. Don't worry if you don't have SD card, it will be copied to a directory called /sdcard
adb push $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.xpi /sdcard/$APP_NAME.xpi;

#5 - This will start the Firefox App with the XPI to install
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -d file:///mnt/sdcard/$APP_NAME.xpi -n $ANDROID_APP_ID/.App;

#6 - Redirect tcp to watch via console
#adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000; #For Firefox for Android 34 and earlier
adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/data/$ANDROID_APP_ID/firefox-debugger-socket #For Firefox for Android 35 and later

#7 - This will wait to you to test your addon and press any key to close Firefox. 
echo ""; read -p "Press 'r' to restart or any other key to close the browser..." pressedKey;

if [ "$pressedKey" == "r" ]; then 
    adb shell am force-stop $ANDROID_APP_ID;

    #8 - This will remove the XPI from the filesystem (but it's still copied on your Firefox)
    adb shell rm /sdcard/$APP_NAME.xpi
    rm $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.xpi;
    echo "Firefox has been forced to stop. Restarting...";
    adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT -n $ANDROID_APP_ID/.App;

    echo ""; read -p "Test your addon on mobile. Press any key to close app..."; 
fi

adb shell am force-stop $ANDROID_APP_ID;
adb shell rm /sdcard/$APP_NAME.xpi
rm $OUTPUT_DIR/$APP_NAME.xpi;
exit 0;
```

Comment: Awesome great solution. Any tips on how to debug/test addon during development? Is connecting android via usb all thats needed? How to push/install from my desktop folder to android for quick testing?

Comment: @Noitidart comments are too small for this response, so I will add it to the answer

Comment: @gal007 great! I'm looking forward to it, I'm going to be starting working heavily on some FxOS apps and this will help me out.

Comment: Hi gal I wrote all the script files and made my xpi but i dont know how to get my addon from my desktop onto my android, how can i do this?

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_for_Android_with_WebIDE and I see my phone and can connect to it from WebIDE but i dont know how to get my extension from desktop to phone.

Comment: Also how can i get the browser console. i can only get per tab console.
i am also wanting to run privelaged code from the browser console. as we can do from browser console (ctrl + shift + j) on desktop

Comment: Hi @gal007 can you answer my question here it would help me a lot! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352289/how-to-get-main-process-in-webide

Comment: I figured out how to install, rather then the long process of adb, i am pushng my extension code to github then installing it on android with this addon straight from github: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/github-extension-installer/  this way is wayyyy too cumbersome they want me to install the whole android sdk crap: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Firefox_for_Android/Walkthrough#Installing_the_add-on