# Simple storage not persisting data between sessions

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-restartless

I'm trying to use the simplestorage from my extension, but I can't retrieve values between browser sessions. Here's the thing: From my main code, I created a value this way:

```
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");
ss.storage.foo = [{id:"bar1", properties:{a:"aaa", b:"bbb"}}]
console.log(ss.storage.foo);
```

This is ok, I coud see the object through the log. But then I closed the browser, commented the "foo definition" (line 2) and the console log was "`undefined`".

I know cfx run by default uses a fresh profile each time it runs, so simple storage won't persist from one run to the next. But I'm using

```
cfx -b firefox run --profiledir=$HOME/.mozilla/firefox/nightly.ext-dev
```

So I'm sure I'm using the same profile everytime.

What could be happening? What am I missing? Any idea is welcome! Thanks in advance!

> Thanks to the answer of Notidart, I could discover that the problem was the file is saved when you close Firefox in the right way. When you just kill it through console, it's not persisting data.

Comment: I recall you worked on firefox addons for mobile and desktop, would you have advice for this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31041439/1828637

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how simple storage works. It creates a folder in your `ProfD` folder which is your profile directory: https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/simple-storage.js#L188

```
let storeFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"].
                getService(Ci.nsIProperties).
                get("ProfD", Ci.nsIFile);
storeFile.append(JETPACK_DIR_BASENAME);
storeFile.append(jpSelf.id);
storeFile.append("simple-storage");
file.mkpath(storeFile.path);
storeFile.append("store.json");
return storeFile.path;
```

The exact location of the file made is in a your profile folder, in a folder named *jetpack* then your *addon id*, then a folder called *simple-storage*, then in a file in that folder called *store.json*. Example path:

```
ProfD/jetpack/addon-id/simple-storage/store.json
```

It then writes data to that file. Every time your profile folder is recreated (due to the nature of temp profile, due to jpm / cfx), your data is erased.

You should just use `OS.File` to create your own file to save data. `OS.File` is better way then `nsIFile` which is what simple-storage does. Save it outside that `ProfD` folder, so but make sure to remove it on uninstall of your addon otherwise you pollute your users computers

Comment: The weird thing is I am forcing to use always the same profile, but I will use my own file and avoit all the problems :) thank you!

Comment: Cound't resist... I readed the file and figures that nothing is being saved! Even during execution time! that's the readon it never persists. And yep, I looked in: $HOME/.mozilla/firefox/nightly.ext-dev/jetpack/jid1-8RskSx1RnMDgug@jetpack/simple-storage/

Comment: The problem was, the file is saved when you close Firefox in the right way. When you just kill it through console, it's not persisting data

Comment: Very interesting share about not saving if improperly shutdown. They should have a backup way to handle that. Let's file a bug, do you know how to do that on http://bugzilla.mozilla.org/?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone else finds this question while using `jpm`, note that `--profiledir` is removed from `jpm`, so to make `jpm run` using the same profile directory (and thereby the same simple-storage data), you have to run it with the `--profile` option pointing at the profile **path** - not the profile name.

```
jpm run --profile path/to/profile
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, an alternative to @Noitidart's recommendation of using `OS.File`, is to use the Low-Level API [`io/file`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file)

You can create a file using [`fileIO.open(path)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/io_file#open(path_mode)). If the file doesn't exist, it will be created. You can read and write by including the second argument `fileIO.open(path, mode)`.

The mode can be:

- `r` - Read-only mode
- `w` - Write-only Mode
- `b` - Binary mode

It defaults to `r`. You can use this to read and write to a file (obviously the file cannot be in the `ProfD` folder or it will get removed each time jpm / cfx is run)