# Browser's HTML5 local storage is not persistent for Firefox Add-ons

Tags: javascript, html, firefox-addon, local-storage

I am coding for a Firefox add-on that uses the local storage of browser to store the values of two variables. When using this is form of general HTML page i get the values of the local storage variables even after closing the browser however when i try doing the same after loading this page by an add-on I get null value for the local storage variables.

*I am able to use the local variables in both the cases till I close the browser. But in case of restarting the browser the local variable value in case of add-on is lost*

The script used for doing this is as follows:-

```
//Fetching the values in the various fields.
//Usermail and password are the ids of two input boxes
//Login is the id for an input button

var id = document.getElementById("usermail");
var pass = document.getElementById("password");
var login = document.getElementById("login");

//Saving the values for the id and password fields

login.addEventListener("click", function() {
    localStorage.setItem("Email", id.value );
    localStorage.setItem("Password", pass.value);
    login_Email = localStorage.getItem("Email"); 
    login_pass = localStorage.getItem("Password"); 
    alert(login_Email); // To check the local storage values 
});
```

*The Add-on is required to store login information of the user to provide access to mail inbox and display the number of unread mails pending. This data needs to be safely stored until a delete request is initiated by the user for this data or a logout request is initiated.*

Comment: Could you provide some details, especially the scope of your addon code?

Comment: Without more information in the question, it appears likely that this is a duplicate of: [Simple storage not persisting data between sessions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061310/simple-storage-not-persisting-data-between-sessions)

Comment: @paa The addon basically emphasizes storing the user information in browser storage even after consecutive restarts until the delete request is initiated by the user.

Comment: Are you using this localStorage from a panel file?

Comment: Yes I am doing it from a js file called via panel for controlling the html file landing in panel