# How to get "Main Process" in WebIDE

Tags: android, firefox, firefox-addon, web-ide

I am trying to run privileged code from the console in WebIDE. My android firefox verison is 39. My desktop firefox version is 38 as I am using Ubuntu so it doenst perfectly sync up with firefox release cycle.

So anyways I followed this tutorial to the T: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android

And I am able to connect to my Firefox on Android on my cellphone (Samsung Galaxy) but I am not able to see "Main Process" in the dropdown here is a screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know what's up? I am starting to develop addons for android, so for installation i will be uploading to github and then installing directly from there with github installer addon.

But to test stuff on the fly it is very critical to use scratchpad or browser console to test code. Editing addon and reinstalling everytime is very cumbersome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connecting to a remote device, like Firefox for Android, it's important for the desktop Firefox to be **the same version or later** than the device, or else you can get some strange behavior like you're seeing here.

So, if you still have 39 on Android, then make sure to use 39 or later on desktop.

Comment: Thanks @jryans Im still stuck on this :( I'm using Ubuntu so I'm getting Ubuntu release, so my desktop version is 38 and my android firefox version is 39, this will never work? Ubuntu comes with firefox installed by default so handles firefox updating weirdly and never auto updates, its not true to the Firefox release cycle. :(

Comment: Maybe you can use [one of the PPAs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FirefoxNewVersion) from the Ubuntu wiki? Or you can also download a Linux build [from Mozilla directly](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/new/?scene=2#download-fx). I regularly run Mozilla's build on Ubuntu for testing, so it should work just fine.

Comment: Oh thanks @jryans! This a complete solution and im finally able to android firefox dev now!